# Hyperledger Fabric Explorer config.json error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-explorer

I am trying to run Explorer 3.6 for fabric version 1.2.0.I am using balance-transfer app for testing.My config.json file is as below-

```
{
  "network-configs": {
    "network-1": {
      "version": "1.0",
      "clients": {
        "client-1": {
          "tlsEnable": true,
          "organization": "Org1MSP",
          "channel": "mychannel",
          "credentialStore": {
            "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Org1/credential",
            "cryptoStore": {
              "path": "./tmp/credentialStore_Org1/crypto"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "channels": {
        "mychannel": {
           "peers":{ "peer0.org1.example.com":{},
        "peer1.org1.example.com": {},
        "peer0.org2.example.com":{},
        "peer1.org2.example.com": {}
    },
          "connection": {
            "timeout": {
              "peer": {
                "endorser": "6000",
                "eventHub": "6000",
                "eventReg": "6000"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "organizations": {
        "Org1MSP": {
          "mspid": "Org1MSP",
          "fullpath": false,
          "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path":
              "/home/ak/fabric-samples/balance-trasnfer/artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore"
          },
          "signedCert": {
            "path":
              "/home/ak/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
          }
    },
        "Org2MSP": {
          "mspid": "Org2MSP",
          "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path":
              "/home/ak/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp/keystore"
          }
        },
        "OrdererMSP": {
          "mspid": "OrdererMSP",
          "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path":
              "/home/ak/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/artifacts/channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp/keystore"
          }
        }
      },
      "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
          "tlsCACerts": {
            "path":
              "/home/ak/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
          },
          "url": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
          "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:7053",
          "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
          }
        },
        "peer1.org1.example.com": {
          "url": "grpcs://localhost:7056",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path":
              "/home/ak/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
          },
          "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:7053",
          "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org1.example.com"
          }
        },
        "peer0.org2.example.com": {
          "url": "grpcs://localhost:9051",
    "tlsCACerts": {
            "path":
              "/home/ak/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
          },
          "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:7053",
          "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org2.example.com"
          }
        },
        "peer1.org2.example.com": {
          "url": "grpcs://localhost:8056",
    "tlsCACerts": {
            "path":
              "/home/ak/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
          },
          "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:7053",
          "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org2.example.com"
          }
        }
      },
      "orderers": {
        "orderer.example.com": {
          "url": "grpcs://localhost:7050",
    "tls_cacerts":"/home/ak/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/artifacts/channel/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "configtxgenToolPath": "/home/ak/fabric-samples/bin",
  "license": "Apache-2.0"
}
```

The error I am getting is:-
Sync process is started for the network : [network-1] and client : [client-1]
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Synchronizer Error >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Error :  [ 'Failed to connect client peer, please check the configuration and peer status' ]
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Closing client processor >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

---

Following is the error log

[2018-09-27 10:58:14.006] [DEBUG] FabricClient - Admin peer Not found for grpcs://localhost:7051

Comment: Same issue for me too. I am working on it.

Comment: Getting same issue

Answer (score 1):

Can you try changing your peer "url" and "eventUrl" in the following format:

```
"url": "grpcs://peer0.org1.example.com:7051"
```

I'm using docker instance to run blockchain explorer and this format works for me.

Comment: Tried your suggestion,but its not working.The connection is being declined on changing localhost to peer0.org1.example.com.

Answer (score 0):

You must find ip and port of running peers and orderer and make changes in config.json. You can use `docker ps` to make sure that containers are running and see the ports related to each container. 
Also, take a look at to [this link](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/blob/master/CONFIG-COMPOSER-HLEXPLORER.md) about Explorer. The link shows the steps needed to change config.json and run explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the sync in the `explorerconfig.json` under `blockchain-explorer/app`

```
"sync": {
"type": "host",
"platform": "fabric",
"blocksSyncTime": "3"
```

}

The error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing the last line (CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT)

```
peer0.org1.example.com:
container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
environment:
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
  - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=info
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
```

in the corresponding docker-compose.yml which describes the network.
Without this line, it seems that peer is only visible inside the org.
You need also to ./generate.sh and ./start.sh your network.
Hope it helps.